# i wanna install Intel Compiler. But sudo command does not work

Tags: command-line, sudo

I write the command like this `sudo ./install.sh`

But ubuntu says

```
sudo: ./install.sh: command not found
```

How can I install this program?

Answer (score 2):

That literally means it can't find the file.

`./install.sh` means execute a file in the current directory called `install.sh`. If you're not in the right directory, you won't have an `install.sh` to execute and that'll exhibit the error you see.

Simply put, you're not following your instructions correctly. If you've extracted an archive from Intel, you likely need to `cd` into it and try again.